# What are the origins of these revolution-era Russia images?

Tags: soviet-union, russia, art

I saw an unrelated image include portions of these images:

[image: A CCCP poster?][image: A related CCCP poster?]

I know they are from the 1918-1932 era of the USSR, judging from the art style, but I can not find titles or translations for them. I also find it interesting that the man in the first image looks like the man in the second image, just years younger.

I am wondering what their origins are and what their subtitles translate to?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure the later is from pre-1932 era. Also note the Ribbon bar on the chest of the man which suggests he is a war veteran.

Comment: @Anixx - Thanks for clarifying what the ribbon symbolizes. I had assumed that the second one was from the same era as the first due to the style, but perhaps it does fit into the approved Socialist Realism style of art as well.

Comment: I think, it's different style. Also the clothing from later period. But anyway it for sure belongs to 1925-1952 because of the name of the party.

Comment: Also the USSR was created in 1922 so the first one for sure cannot be from 1918. The cited first article of the constitution belongs to the constitution of 1936. The image clearly attributes it to the constitution (by small font below the phrase it says "from the constitution of the Soviet Union" and the entire phrase is in the quotes.

Comment: So my guess is that the first one is from 1936-1937 (because later citing the first article of the constitution would look too trivial, but the same year the constitution was adopted it's ok) while the second one is from 1950-1952.

Comment: @Anixx, thanks for your research. Those images were created much later than I imagined, and I definitely didn't think that either one was created post-Lenin.

Comment: Also note that the girl has a badge of the Komsomol similar to this: http://logoyek.ru/preview/3_vlksm.gif It was adopted in 1944, so the second picture is definitely from a post-WW2 period.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first one says USSR (right below the star) The Union of Soviet Socialist Republics is a socialist state of workers and peasants. See [constitution of the USSR](http://www.departments.bucknell.edu/russian/const/36cons01.html), Article 1.

The second one says
"VKP(b)" in the top-right corner meaning All-Russian Communist Party (bolsheviks) or All-Union Communist Party (bolsheviks).
Then

> "We'll raise a generation, selflessly loyal to communist endeavor"

or

> "Let's raise a generation, selflessly loyal to communist endeavor",

depending on how you interpret it.

Comment: Close enough for government work as far as translations go :))) (j/k - it's very close, I would only suggest tweaking the last one from "to communism" to "to communist endeavor"). +1

Comment: Indeed, it's "communist endeavor".

Answer (score 15):

The USSR was created in 1922 so the first one for sure cannot be from 1918. The cited first article of the constitution belongs to the constitution of 1936. The image clearly attributes it to the constitution (by small font below the phrase it says "from the constitution of the Soviet Union" and the entire phrase is in the quotes. So my guess is that the first one is from 1936-1937 (because later citing the first article of the constitution would look too trivial, but the same year the constitution was adopted it's ok).

Regarding the second one, it is clearly from post-WWII era. Note the ribbon bar on the chest of the man which suggests he is a war veteran. Also note that the girl has a badge of the Komsomol similar to this: [image: http://logoyek.ru/preview/3_vlksm.gif]

This design was adopted in 1944, so the second picture is definitely from a post-WW2 period, but not later than 1952 due to the name of the party VKP(b). I guess it is from 1950-1952.

P.S. The images themselves have dates, the first one is from 1945, the second one is from 1947.